# Adding a time to a cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am working on a simple web application that:

1. Adds table rows to a BS HTML website.
2. Has a function that adds the current time to a table cell with an onclick event.

Right now I'm having trouble finding some examples, I am able to execute the onclick event when linking a button to a text area, but how can I achieve this with a table cell?

Many thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="surgeonRequest' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="scrubCallout' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="implantUsed' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="implantRemoved' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nurseRecord' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });


});



function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

//Timestamp Javascript

function getTimeStamp() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}

window.onclick = "getTimeStamp" ;
</script>


<!-- BEGIN HTML -->

<!-- Tables -->
<div class="fluid-container">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><center><b>Item</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Surgeon Request</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Scrub Callout</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Implant Used</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Implant Removed</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>EHR Record</b></center></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" onclick="this.name.value=getTimeStamp()/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="surgeonRequest"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="scrubCallout"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="implantUsed"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="implantRemoved"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="nurseRecord"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;">
              <center>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-lg " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
              </center>
            </td>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you want to add the time

Comment: The time would added to each cell when the user clicked on the cell.

Comment: where in each cell? which input box? explain how do you want to use it so that i can help with code

Comment: Many thanks, the goal is to have an event onclick in "surgeonRequest, scrubCallout, implantUsed, implantRemoved, nurseRecord" where the empty cell is replaced with a timestamp from the getTimeStamp() function. This would pull the now.getDate and replace the blank/empty field in each text type cell with the text generated from getTimeStamp().

Comment: ok great, answering now

Comment: please upvote the answer too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's a typo in your code above at onclick line where it doesn't close the `"`. Anyway, here's the complete modified code, please check and see if it solves your problem.

Note that I have modified both html and javascript part

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item' + counter + '"  onClick="this.value=getTimeStamp()" /></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="surgeonRequest' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="scrubCallout' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="implantUsed' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="implantRemoved' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nurseRecord' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });



    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });


});



function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();

}

function calculateGrandTotal() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="price"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}

//Timestamp Javascript
window.getbla = function(){
alert("hi");
return "bla";
};

window.getTimeStamp = function() {
       var now = new Date();
       return ((now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (now.getDate()) + '/' + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ':'
                     + ((now.getMinutes() < 10) ? ("0" + now.getMinutes()) : (now.getMinutes())) + ':' + ((now.getSeconds() < 10) ? ("0" + now
                     .getSeconds()) : (now.getSeconds())));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BEGIN HTML -->

<!-- Tables -->
<div class="fluid-container">
    <table id="myTable" class=" table order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><center><b>Item</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Surgeon Request</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Scrub Callout</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Implant Used</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>Implant Removed</b></center></td>
            <td><center><b>EHR Record</b></center></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" onClick="this.value=getTimeStamp()">
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="surgeonRequest"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="scrubCallout"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="implantUsed"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="implantRemoved"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" name="nurseRecord"  class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-2"><a class="deleteRow"></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" style="text-align: left;">
              <center>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-lg " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
              </center>
            </td>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3he1962o/15/

I hope it helps.